# How to do with hibernate Criteria to get the right result

Tags: hibernate

I have two classes named Expert and Technology, an expert can maitrise several technologies, a technology is matrised by several experts. Adding, updating a technology is independent from class Expert. Remove a maitrised technology from the experts remove only the associated relation.

```
Class Expert{
     Long id; // getter and setter
     String name; // getter and setter;
     Set<Technology> technos; // getter and setter
} 

Technology{
     Long id; // gettter and setter
     String name; //getter and setter
}
```

The relation between the two classes reflected in the hibernate mapping is

```
<class name="Expert">
    <!-- put the declaration for id and name --> 

    <set name="technos" table="EXPERT_TECHNO" cascade="delete-orphan">
            <key column="id_expert"/>
            <many-to-many column="id_techno" class = "Technology"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Technology">
 <!-- put declaration for id and name-->
</class>
```

Now I have a instance of Technology, I want to find all experts who maitrise the technology, so how to use hibernate critera to get the result set? Or the simplest way to get the result set using createQuery.

I am not famillar to hibernate critera method, so i call for your helps!

Further question:

when I want a remove a technology from expert, what I want is simply remove a line in the table "EXPET_TECHNO", howevery, what I had is that expert.getTechnos.remove(techno),will remove the technology from the table which is what I don't want to have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the easiest way to solve this problem would be to make the ManyToMany association bidirectional. You would just have to do

```
Set<Expert> experts = technology.getExperts();
```

Now, if it's not an option, HQL would be easier than Criteria for such a query, which is not dynamically composed. The query would be as simple as

```
select expert from Expert expert 
inner join expert.technos techno 
where techno.id = :technoId
```

If you really really want to do this with Criteria, then you need to do the following:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Expert.class, "expert");
c.createAlias("expert.technos", "techno");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("techno.id", technoId));
```

You could have found this by yourself and learnt many other things by reading the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations).

Comment: Yes, i've found, the createAlias function is misleading. Thanks very much for your sulution.

Comment: Another question for you, how to deal with the update, remove, using criteria for many-to-many association?

Comment: A criteria query can only select from the database. To remove or update an association, remove or update entities from/in the collection of technos of the retrieved experts.